# Multi values or multi index pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a sample data data table like

```
import pandas as pd

compnaies = ['Microsoft', 'Google', 'Amazon', 'Microsoft', 'Facebook', 'Google']
products = ['OS', 'Search', 'E-comm', 'E-comm', 'Social Media', 'OS']
count = [5,7,3,19,23,54]
average = [1.2,3.4,2.4,5.2,3.2,4.4]

df = pd.DataFrame({'company' : compnaies, 'product':products,
                   'count':count , 'average' : average})
df

    average company count   product
0   1.2 Microsoft   5   OS
1   3.4 Google      7   Search
2   2.4 Amazon      3   E-comm
3   5.2 Microsoft   19  E-comm
4   3.2 Facebook    23  Social Media
5   4.4 Google      54  OS
```

Now I want to create pivot view on both 'average' and 'count' but I am not able to define both values, here the sample code with one 'average'

```
df.pivot_table(index='company', columns='product', values='average', fill_value=0)
```

the output will be

[image]

but I need the data in below format, can someone please help meanwhile I tried the stack, and group by which creates multi index data frame but it does not give desired output, I will share the code if needed

desired output which I need to download in excel

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(['company','product'])
       .stack()
       .unstack(axis=1)
       .rename_axis([None, None])
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
                   E-comm    OS  Search  Social Media
Amazon    count       3.0   NaN     NaN           NaN
          average     2.4   NaN     NaN           NaN
Facebook  count       NaN   NaN     NaN          23.0
          average     NaN   NaN     NaN           3.2
Google    count       NaN  54.0     7.0           NaN
          average     NaN   4.4     3.4           NaN
Microsoft count      19.0   5.0     NaN           NaN
          average     5.2   1.2     NaN           NaN
```

Comment: thanks and really great, I admire you a lot...I wish if I can follow you anywhere